# Translate mouse coordinates to child panel

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I'm creating simple Java game, which would have separate JPanels for each game state. In the code below they're hiding under `AbstractPanel`. But I have key/mouse listeners on the top panel ( `Game` ).

Unfortunately, when I'm trying to use mouse coordinates from `Game` on `currentPanel` subpanel, components on subpanel got highlighted too early, e.g. JButton located on 100,100 gets highlighted when mouse cursor is on 90,90. Is there a way to translate coordinates from parent panel to child?

```java
public class Game extends JPanel implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private static final int WIDTH = 1024;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 768;

    private AbstractPanel currentPanel = null;

    public Game() {

        Dimension gameSize = new Dimension( WIDTH, HEIGHT );
        menuPanel.setSize( gameSize );
        menuPanel.setPreferredSize( gameSize );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        Game game = new Game();
        game.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        Dimension gameSize = new Dimension( WIDTH, HEIGHT );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        frame.getContentPane().add( game, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        frame.setSize( gameSize );
        frame.setPreferredSize( gameSize );
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.addKeyListener( game );
        frame.addMouseListener( game );
        frame.addMouseMotionListener( game );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {

        currentPanel.mousePressed( e );
        repaint();
    }
```

Comment: maybe [getMousePosition](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Container.html#getMousePosition(boolean)), [convertPoint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPoint(java.awt.Component,int,int,java.awt.Component)), [convertPointFromScreen](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPointFromScreen(java.awt.Point,java.awt.Component))

Comment: Yes, it works. Just need to pass `JFrame` instead of `Game` as listeners are on `JFrame`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else needs the answer, here's my update: mouse methods in main class are passing parent `JFrame` like this:

```java
    public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e ) {

        currentPanel.mousePressed( frame, e );
        repaint();
    }
```

and in subpanels these listeners start with conversion:

```java
    @Override
    public void mousePressed( Container source, MouseEvent e ) {

        String newItem = null;
        Point clickPoint = SwingUtilities.convertPoint( source, e.getX(), e.getY(), this );
        // some code here
        if( bounds.contains( clickPoint ) ) {
        // some more code here
```

Thanks to [Carlos Heuberger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85421/carlos-heuberger) in the comment above.